# Opening file from AWS S3 bucket on jupyter notebok

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, boto3

I am trying to open a file I uploaded on a S3 bucket from a jupyter notebook.

I've go the following code for uploading a file from the notebook

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id="YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID", 
aws_secret_access_key="YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")

s3 = session.resource("s3")

my_bucket = s3.create_bucket(Bucket="a-bucket-name")



csv = data.to_csv() #data is a dataframe I already defined
put_object = my_bucket.put_object(Key="test.csv", Body=csv)
```

However I don't know how to do this the otherway around to open/download a file from my notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aramis you can use [download_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_file).

Comment: my code works just fine. Do you know how I can download a file? since the upload is already working

Comment: @aramis you can use [download_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_file).

Answer (score 0):

You can download using the same S3 client:

```
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key).get()
print(obj['Body'].read())
```

Comment: it's returning the following 
AttributeError: 's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'get_object

Comment: It's still not working, I think the issue is with the get_object, returns same error